# Multicolumn with overflow in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, multiple-columns

I try to use multi-column in CSS3. I have problem with Chrome when I scroll. The items disappear under the first column. Is ok with IE11, but not with Chrome (and Firefox break-Inside not working, but is not important, for now).

http://jsfiddle.net/PwzMh/3/ for view my exemple

This part does not disappear

```
<li class="nomlocalisation">LOCALISATION</li>
```

but this is disappear

```
<li class="tag">
    <div class="barre">
        <span class="metier">
            <span id="dateemb">1900-01-01</span>
            <span id="matnom">0002 LASTNAME FIRSTNAME</span>
        </span>
        <span id="elipse">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
</li>
```

Any idea how to solve that ?

Thank you

Comment: everything's ok for me on chrome v31. Which version of chrome do you use ?!

Comment: I use v32. I have this problem since many month/year. In jsfiddle, Do you see 2 column before scroll ? When you scroll, the 2 first tag in second column, the text and the green background will disapper. The first column is always ok.

Comment: ho, got it ! my window was too small so i can't see the bug. Now i see the issue. When you remove the overflow:auto, it works. It's like the problem comes with the container `#selectableHaut`. But now, can't see how to fix ...